# Flutter error: Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to sign and publish the project and when I run "flutter build appbundle" I get the following error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

my key.properties file:

```
storePassword=dehset21    
keyPassword=dehset21
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=E:/ariyorum/android/app/upload-keystore.jks
```

i think i did the steps correctly and i couldn't find a solution when i searched for this error on the internet.

my build.gradle file:
above android tag there is the code

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

in android tag:

```
    signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I moved the key.properties file into the android folder. I created a new key and placed it in the android/app folder. With this method i fix it,thanks :)

Comment: In my case it was enough to move the file `key.properties` to `android/`. I didn't have to re-create`upload-keystore.jks` and just left it in my home folder.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with my Flutter project and managed to resolve it by moving the key.properties file inside the root of the android folder. The path for the key.properties file should be `android/key.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if your key.jks name is.
`storePassword=your-key-pass
keyPassword=your-key-pass
keyAlias=my-key-alias
```

`storeFile=../app/src/my-key.jksmy-key.jks` then use  this alias my-key-alias and try correcting the location of your.    storefile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).